# Why do we need to use visudo instead of directly modifying the sudoers file?

Tags: sudo

I understand that if you want to modify who can use `sudo` and what they can do with it that you should use `visudo`.  I know I'm not supposed to directly modify the /etc/sudoers file myself.

What is it that `visudo` does that directly modifying the file doesn't do? What can go wrong?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`visudo` checks the file syntax *before* actually overwriting the `sudoers` file.

If you use a plain editor, mess up the syntax, and save... `sudo` will (probably) stop working, and, since `/etc/sudoers` is only modifiable by `root`, you're stuck (unless you have another way of gaining root).

Additionally it ensures that the edits will be one atomic operation. This locking is important if you need to ensure nobody else can mess up your carefully considered config changes. For editing other files as root besides `/etc/sudoers` there is the `sudoedit` command which also guard against such editing conflicts.

Comment: Wow, never knew about sudoedit.  It doesn't work on OS X so I assume it's a GNU tool?  Anyway, cool info here.  I'd always edited manually and never had a problem - I understand now that it was just luck and the tool can help prevent catastrophe.  Thanks!

Comment: @Harv. There is no GNU `sudo` and OS X does have GNU tools. As sudo was first created as an open source application, there's probably no reason for their being many implementations. `sudo` and `sudoedit` are the same command, `sudo` behaves as `sudo -e` when called as `sudoedit`. I believe it's just that OS X forgot to add the `sudoedit -> sudo` link, but you should still be able to use `sudo -e` or call `sudo` with argv[0] set to `sudoedit` to get the same behavior.

Comment: Interestingly, `visudo` uses nano by default.

Comment: @Tim: The "real" default is vi, but it can be configured to use something else. So nano could indeed be the default on your distro/setup. See the [man page](http://www.sudo.ws/visudo.man.html).

Comment: _you're stuck_ - so what to do then? :) and can you please elaborate please on the consequences?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas macOS user here. I can confirm that `ln -s /usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/sudoedit` (actually anywhere in `$PATH`) works.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, the consequences are pretty obvious. If you save an invalid sudoers file, then the system will not be able to parse it. So if I do a `sudo vim /etc/sudoers` and botch the syntax, then I will not be able to `sudo vim /etc/sudoers` again to fix it. Effectively, all ability to elevate privileges via sudo will be lost since the system will not be able to parse the file.

Answer (score 27):

From the visudo man page:

> visudo locks the sudoers file against multiple simultaneous edits,
>   provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors. If the
>   sudoers file is currently being edited you will receive a message to
>   try again later.

Also check this [answer from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/26306/89607).