# How to reduce chances of editing sudoers with other editors?

Tags: shell, sudo

Yes, [it is recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/why-do-we-need-to-use-visudo-instead-of-directly-modifying-the-sudoers-file) to use `visudo` to edit sudoers file. But I'm not satisfied with verbally recommending it. Can shell give a warning or require a confirmation when I'm editing the file in a wrong way?

I would like to catch the following situations:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/sudoers
/etc $ sudo nano sudoers
$ sudo cp what/ever/file /etc/sudoers.d/a
```

Comment: Nothing keeps an administrator from doing bad stuff. Where do you stop? What about `rm sudoers` or `cat > sudoers`? With great `sudo` comes great responsibility.

Comment: First lines of my `sudoers` file are
`#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#`

Comment: @pLumo then how about `cat > sudoers`?

Comment: I can't get - what's wrong or bad in doing `sudo nano /etc/sudoers` or maybe `sudo mcedit /etc/sudoers` - what if vi/vim is not "my favorite editor of all times" and I like and have installed something else, for example Mindnight Commander which features "mcedit"?

Comment: @ivan.ukr This is not about `vi` vs `nano`, but `visudo` vs any other means of editing the file. `visudo` can use `nano` or whatever Editor is set as default.

Comment: `visudo` checks that `/etc/sudoers` has valid syntax after editing, no matter what editor is used, and refuses to replace it if it's invalid.   `sudo "$EDITOR" /etc/sudoers` does **not** do any checking, which means you can easily find yourself with a broken sudoers file (and unable to use sudo to fix it - better hope that root has a password so you can use `su` instead).

Comment: note: "valid syntax" is not the same as "does what you want/meant".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm here to present my awkward solution. I'm using zsh and it is a zsh widget (command line plugin).

When the current directory is `sudoders.d`, or the command line contains `sudoers`, zsh will give a warning, unless the command is "cd" or "visudo".

The code covers the senarios of vim, nano, cp, rm, cat > .

I believe you may make it better, but that's the basic idea.

```
#! /usr/bin/zsh


function catchEditSudoers {
    if ([[ $BUFFER =~ .*sudoers.* ]] && [[ ! $BUFFER =~ .*visudo.* ]] && [[ ! $BUFFER =~ "cd .*" ]]) ||
        ([[ $PWD =~ ".*/sudoers.d" ]] && [[ ! $BUFFER =~ .*visudo.* ]] && [[ ! $BUFFER =~ "cd .*" ]]); then
        zle -R "It's recommanded to use visudo to edit sudoers. Continue anyway? (y/n)"
        read -k reply
        if [[ $reply == y ]]; then
            zle accept-line
        else
            zle send-break
        fi

    else
        zle accept-line
    fi
}

zle -N catchEditSudoers_widget catchEditSudoers

bindkey '^M' catchEditSudoers_widget
```

Source the file in your .zshrc.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I would not do the following. It is not safe, and also there are enough other possibilites to destroy your system. Why exactly picking this one?

With great `sudo` rights, comes great responsibility.

---

However, to keep even `root` from editing `sudoers` file, you can make it immutable by running:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/sudoers
```

Then add the followign aliases to your `.rc` or `.profile` file, e.g. `.bashrc`:

```
alias visudo="sudo chattr -i /etc/sudoers; sudo visudo; sudo chattr +i /etc/sudoers;"
alias sudo='sudo '
```

It will change `visudo` command to first reset immutable flag, then run `visudo` , at the end make it `immutable` again. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo) why we need the second alias.

After resourcing the file or restarting the shell, you can use `sudo visudo` as normal, but not edit it otherwise.

---

This is just the general idea, it needs to be enhanced to enable other arguments of `visudo` and the files below `/etc/sudoers.d/`. Instead of an alias, you could also use a function or script.

---

Note, this is not really safe:

- the moments you have `visudo` running, the file is not immutable
- any `sudo` user can run `chattr -i` to unset the immutable flag at any time
- you train yourself a behavior to not think before doing stuff

Comment: That's awesome. I came up with another idea. As I'm using zsh, I learned it supports preexec hook. Would the hook be able to cancel a command? Or are there any widgets that could do this?